# Как отформатировать текст?

Tags: html, вёрстка-email

"Оформите предоплату на журнал" как сделать чтобы первые два слова были одного цвета и размера, а последнее другого. Только не используя css (верстка для email рассылок). Помогите! Буду очень признательна))

Comment: Почему без CSS? Мылохранилища допускают безопасные стили. Правда извечный вопрос - что считается безопасным в клиенте X? Но цвет и размер поменять дадут все.

Comment: без CSS вам не обойтись. Но вписывать его в отдельный файл не надо. Вы можете прописать все свойства в примере самом `<div></div>`

Comment: Я бы начал с форматирования правописания...

Comment: @Other, я читал недавно о HTML-письмах и наткнулся на статью: [**Программируйте как в 1997. Так что пора забыть (временно) о ваших любимых CSS стилях и вспомнить о массивных таблицах**](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=861). У Вас другое мнение? Спасибо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @СашаЧерных, что сказать - на данный момент это правда. Конечно, подвижки в сторону поддержки и удобства есть, но корявые и костыльные. Стандарта и спецификации требует народ, а их нет.

Answer (score 5):

Такой формат можно рассылать, css внутри. Другим способом нельзя никак.

```html
<div><span style="color:blue;font-size:18px;">Оформити передплату</span> на <span style="color:orange;">журнал</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно и вообще без CSS — тегом `<font>`. Он считается устаревшим, но поддерживается всеми браузерами до сих пор.

```html
<div><font color="blue" size="5">Оформите передплату</font> на <font color="orange">журнал</font></div>
```

Но я думаю, можно и стилями внутри тегов обойтись, как в другом ответе, для мыла должно быть приемлимо.